# PyAudio stream read is blocking (no data) on device with ALSA and pulseaudio

Tags: python, alsa, pyaudio, pulseaudio

I'm trying to get audio data in Python on a Linux device that runs PulseAudio.

The previous environment in which pyaudio worked was just ALSA. 
Now the environment runs PulseAudio. I've hooked ALSA into PulseAudio by setting the default ALSA device to be a pulse.

`arecord -f dat test.wav` and then `aplay test.wav` work fine for me right now.

However, it seems like pyaudio does not work under these settings.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

stream.read(CHUNK)
```

`stream.read()` hangs. `strace` shows it stuck in a loop of:

```
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLNVAL}], 1, 3) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
```

I guess the meta question here is, does a stack of pyaudio -> port audio -> alsa -> PulseAudio work? If not, is there a canonical way of getting audio in Python from PulseAudio? A lot of the top of the python/PulseAudio libraries out there have not had any activity in the past couple years.

My asound.conf looks something like this

```
pcm.!default{
type plug
route_policy "average"
slave.pcm "asymed"
}

pcm.asymed{
type asym
playback.pcm "pulse_playback"
capture.pcm "pulse_capture"
}

pcm.pulse_playback {
type pulse
device "alsa_output.platform-sound_0.analog-stereo"
}

pcm.pulse_capture {
type pulse
device "alsa_input.platform-sound_1.analog-stereo"
}
```

Comment: Your parameters correspond to `-f cd`; does that work with `arecord`? Which device is `pyaudio` using?

Comment: -f cd works. my asound.conf specifies pulseaudio as the default device (which is probably how arecord/aplay work without specifying device) so pyaudio should probably be using that. but I have also tried manually passing in input_device_index for the default device.